# Selecting top values from columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find top 5 countries with highest population per continent. I just want to use below 1 table:

URL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Database:
world database (MyISAM version, used in MySQL certifications and training)

Below is what I came up with:

```
select Continent,
substring_index(
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct cast(Name as char)), ',', 5)
From
country
group by
Continent,Name;
```

Thanks,
Rio

Answer (score 0):

This one is with `correlated sub-query`:

```
SELECT c.name, c.continent 
WHERE population IN (SELECT population 
                    FROM country c1
                    WHERE c.continent = c1.continent
                    ORDER by population
                    LIMIT 5)
FROM country c
```

Not having database schema I made some assumptions about its fields.